# Software to commnicate with Android App over USB connection

Tags: android, usb

An application in my pc [Which i don't have and searching for it] that can communicate with an app installed in my android powered device. My android device is connected to PC using USB cable, an example that i came around was Multi Port Terminal, tried it but doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please try to be more specific.

Comment: Pls add up more details